# Homestead multiple sites issue

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I added two sites in Sites section in homestead.yaml file the bluprint of my homestead.yaml file is below

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: site1.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site1/public
    - map: site2.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/site2/public

databases:
    - site1

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

#services:
#    - enabled:
#        - "postgresql@12-main"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I added those two sites in my /etc/hosts file as well blueprint is below

```
192.168.10.10 site1.local
192.168.10.10 site2.local
```

**and then I runned homestead provision**.

When i run site1.local or site2.local they both show me the content of site1.local files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by installing homestead again